# Как конфигурировать меню в Bot Api?

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Всем привет.
Только начал изучать создание тг бота + php, поэтому иногда туплю.
Подскажите, что отвечает за создание меню с кнопками, как на изображении.

Не буду против отправки какого-то мануала на русском.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61300231/12785139

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно предоставлять параметр reply_markup как сериализованный объект JSON

```
$replyMarkup = array(
    'keyboard' => array(
        array("товары", "заказ")
    )
);
$encodedMarkup = json_encode($replyMarkup);
$content = array(
    'chat_id' => <chat_id>,
    'reply_markup' => $encodedMarkup,
    'text' => "меню магазина:"
);
```